# A0N size is different than expected when printed

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I have a strange problem. I got a new ZT220 printer (203 dpi - 8dpmm) and when I use simple A0N sizing to adjust font it prints font of incorrect size.

For example a simple code:

```
^XA
^A0N,80^FO80,80^FD1^FS
^XZ
```

Should print number `1` exactly 1 centimeter tall (`80 / 8 = 10mm`), yet it comes out at around 7mm. Any advice?

When I print a graphic, for example a box:

```
^XA
^FO80,80^GB80,80,1,B,0^FS
^XZ
```

This box comes out precisely 10x10mm.

Why is it that the font doesn't scale properly?
Note that I'm new to ZPL and this is my first Zebra printer. I use Ubuntu environment to send files to print, e.g.:

```
lpr -P <printer name> -o raw text.zpl
```

All I did was connect the printer through CUPS. Do I have to install the `default` fonts? If yes how do I do that on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The space for characters is what you are specifying. Not all characters take up the full space. For example a lower case 'g' or 'p' would go below the bottom of the '1' character.

Also, different fonts may act differently. Try below to see how differently some behave.

```
^XA
^A0N,80^FO80,100^FD1gpi|0^FS
^FO80,100^GB400,80,1,B,0^FS
^A1N,80^FO80,200^FD1gpi|0^FS
^FO80,200^GB400,80,1,B,0^FS
^AbN,80^FO80,300^FD1gpi|0^FS
^FO80,300^GB400,80,1,B,0^FS
^AcN,80^FO80,400^FD1gpi|0^FS
^FO80,400^GB400,80,1,B,0^FS
^AeN,80^FO80,500^FD1gpi|0^FS
^FO80,500^GB400,80,1,B,0^FS
^AfN,80^FO80,600^FD1gpi|0^FS
^FO80,600^GB400,80,1,B,0^FS
^XZ
```